# Parameter binding error in Icarus Verilog

Tags: verilog, shift-register, testbench

I am trying to design a shift register that can have both serial and parallel outputs. My implementation is posted below:

```
module SR #(parameter SIZE = 10, parameter OUT = 1)( out_p, out_s, in_p, in_s, load, clk, reset_n);

input [SIZE-1:0] in_p; 
input in_s; 

input clk;
input reset_n;

input load;


output [SIZE-1:0]out_p; // parallel output
output out_s; // serial output

reg [SIZE-1:0] temp;


always @ (posedge clk, negedge reset_n)
begin
    if (reset_n)
        out <= 4'b0;
    else begin
        if (load)
             temp <= in;
        else temp <= {in_s, temp[SIZE-1:1]};
    end     
end

if (load)
    assign out_p = temp;
else
    assign out_s = temp[0];

endmodule

`timescale 1ns/100ps

module SR_tb;

parameter SIZE = 4;
parameter OUT = 0; // parallel output 

reg clk;
reg reset_n;

initial begin
    clk <= 0;
    reset_n <= 0;
    # 150 reset_n <= 1;
end

always @(clk) #10 clk <= ~clk; 


reg [SIZE-1:0] in_p;
reg in_s;
reg load;

wire [SIZE-1:0] out_p;
wire out_s;



SR #(.SIZE(VEC_SIZE), .OUT(OUT)) dut(.clk(clk), .reset_n(reset_n), .in_p(in_p), .in_s(in_s), .load(load), .out_p(out_p), .out_s(out_s));

initial begin


#5 reset_n <= 0;
   in_s <= 1'b0;
   load <= 1'b0;
#2 load <= 1'b1;

in_p <= 4'b1100;

reset_n <= 1;
load <= 1'b0;
in_s <= 1'bx;

#1000 $finish;  
end

initial begin
$dumpfile("SR.vcd");
$dumpvars(0, dut);

end
endmodule
```

When I try simulating in Icarus Verilog I get the error below:

```
sr.v:29: error: Unable to bind parameter `load' in `SR_tb.dut'                                                 
sr.v:29: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: load                                            
sr.v:29: error: Unable to bind parameter `load' in `SR_tb.dut'                                                 
sr.v:29: error: Cannot evaluate genvar conditional expression: load                                            
4 error(s) during elaboration.
```

I would appreciated it if you could tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `if` construct outside a procedural block (`initial` or `always`) That makes it a non-procedural *if-generate* construct which means the conditional needs to be a constant expression (literal constant numbers or parameters), not an input to the module.

The basic problem comes down to what do you want the outputs `out_p` and `out_s` to have during the time `load` is true or false? It has to be something. I'm guessing you can either eliminate the `if` statement altogether, or use a conditional operator to make the high-impedance

```
assign out_p = temp;
assign out_s = temp[0];

assign out_p = load ? temp : {SIZE{1'bz}};
assign out_s = load ? 1'bz : temp[0];
```